# How to sum n % of values in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to sum let's say 50 % of all values ordered by value in my Postgres table?

In table I have values `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6` and I'd like to get the sum of half values ordered by value DESC. So the result would be `4 + 5 + 6 = 15`

Also, I might want to get only 1/3 of values so I would get `6 + 5 = 11`

Is it possible with SQL in Postgres? Something like

```
SELECT sum(value)
FROM (
       SELECT value
       FROM table
       ORDER BY value DESC
       LIMIT 50%
     ) subquery
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version I came up with:

```
SELECT sum(value)
FROM (
       SELECT
         value,
         ntile(10)
         OVER (
           ORDER BY value DESC ) AS tile
       FROM t
     ) subquery
WHERE tile >= 10*0.5;
```

That doesn't work for `count of values < ntile's N` but in the end I plan to use it for thousands of values

Answer (score 1):

I would use `row_number()` and `count()`:

```
SELECT sum(value)
FROM (SELECT value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value) as seqnum,
             COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt
      FROM table
     ) subquery
WHERE seqnum <= cnt * 0.5;
```

Comment: i would extract the `COUNT(*)` in a `WITH` : `with total as (select count(*) from table) ....` (more elegant imo)

Comment: It requeries to add `GROUP BY` when using `COUNT` there and didn't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

[`percent_rank`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
with t (value) as (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6))
select sum(value)
from (
    select value, percent_rank() over (order by value) as pr
    from t
) S
where pr > 0.5
;
 sum 
-----
  15
```

Comment: Looking good but found out it doesn't work with rare case `with t (value) as (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))`